# Will a lazy susan in the pan mechanism of my pan-tilt system be suitable?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, bearings, machine-design

Currently, I'm trying to up with a design for the pan mechanism. The pan-tilt system itself will be mounted with a couple different antennas such as yagi-uda and  patch antenna. I'm designing the system for a max payload of 50kg with azimuth and elevation speeds around 8-12 deg/s. Will a lazy susan turntable bearing ([like these ones](https://www.bearing-king.co.uk/all-lazy-susan-turntable-bearings)) be suitable in my application?
[image]

Comment: if they can support the weight, then why not use them?

Comment: @jsotola I want to confirm if it is suitable for my specific application. I have lacking knowledge in this matter and can't find much online that could assuage my concerns of all the things I'm ignorantly unaware of.

Comment: you did not specify any requirements, other than the load weight and rotational motion ... the devices you linked are a good place to start in the development of your device ... other requirments may become evident as you run tests

Comment: The max payload isn't the only limiting factor. You must take into the account the environmental stress (water, ice, sand...) and the torque caused by the tilting motion non-centered load + wind. Do NOT build anything without knowing these stresses and how your planned bearing component tolerates them. BTW I guess you can see how to connect the pan motor so that only rotation stresses the motor (=no axial push nor pull nor bending) The motor shaft or motor body mounting should create that capability.

Answer (score 0):

If, by "lazy susan", you mean a needle roller bearing of sufficient diameter and capacity to support the load then yes.

Comment: I'm referring to a lazy susan turntable bearings like this [one](https://www.amazon.com/Square-Inch-Susan-Turntable-Bearing/dp/B017OYZAHW/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=turntable+bearing&qid=1662307999&sr=8-3)

Comment: @xrosaber and I am referring to bearings that support axial loads.

Comment: I want to reduce the axial load on the pan motor, I don't understand how a needle roller bearing will help with that. I'm lacking in knowledge so please bear with me.